# After adding Xavier and bias_filler, the loss values starts becoming negative. Why?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

After I added `xavier` initialization to every convolution layer, the loss starts becoming **negative**. Could someone give any suggestion/reason?
I added the following lines to all convolutional layers:

```
weight_filler {
          type: "xavier"
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0.1
        }
```

---

```
I0305 14:31:53.356343 11179 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 0 (-4.02766e+28 iter/s, 0.528933s/100 iters), loss = 2.05371
I0305 14:31:53.356374 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.11937
I0305 14:31:53.356384 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 2.05371 (* 1 = 2.05371 loss)
I0305 14:31:53.356395 11179 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 0, lr = 0.0001
I0305 14:32:28.728870 11179 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 100 (2.82699 iter/s, 35.3733s/100 iters), loss = 0.0270034
I0305 14:32:28.729014 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 1
I0305 14:32:28.729028 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I0305 14:32:28.729034 11179 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 100, lr = 0.0001
I0305 14:33:03.729997 11179 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 200 (2.85701 iter/s, 35.0017s/100 iters), loss = -8.27284e-09
I0305 14:33:03.730154 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 1
I0305 14:33:03.730167 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I0305 14:33:03.730172 11179 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 200, lr = 0.0001
I0305 14:33:38.885211 11179 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 300 (2.84449 iter/s, 35.1557s/100 iters), loss = -8.27284e-09
I0305 14:33:38.885368 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 1
I0305 14:33:38.885383 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I0305 14:33:38.885387 11179 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 300, lr = 0.0001
I0305 14:34:14.174548 11179 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 400 (2.83368 iter/s, 35.2898s/100 iters), loss = -8.27284e-09
I0305 14:34:14.174702 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 1
I0305 14:34:14.174720 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I0305 14:34:14.174724 11179 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 400, lr = 0.0001
I0305 14:34:49.578112 11179 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 500 (2.82453 iter/s, 35.4041s/100 iters), loss = -8.27284e-09
I0305 14:34:49.578254 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 1
I0305 14:34:49.578269 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I0305 14:34:49.578272 11179 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 500, lr = 0.0001
I0305 14:35:25.042238 11179 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 600 (2.81971 iter/s, 35.4646s/100 iters), loss = -8.27284e-09
I0305 14:35:25.042421 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 1
I0305 14:35:25.042438 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I0305 14:35:25.042443 11179 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 600, lr = 0.0001
I0305 14:36:00.540053 11179 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 700 (2.81704 iter/s, 35.4983s/100 iters), loss = -8.27284e-09
I0305 14:36:00.540194 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 1
I0305 14:36:00.540207 11179 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss =
```

My another question is that in some networks, `Gaussian` is added. Like:

```
weight_filler {
   type: "gaussian"
   std: 0.005
}
bias_filler {
    type: "constant"
    value: 0.1
}
```

1. Why are we adding these parameters to convolutional layer? Is it
   because we are training the network from the scratch?
2. How are a specific value assigned to `std` and/or the `bias_filler`
   value?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your loss is `-8.27284e-09` which practically speaking is zero and not negative (caffe is using a single precision floating point numbers and not double precision).
  What loss layer are you using? `"SoftmaxWithLoss"`?
- `bias_filler` and `wieght_filler` parameters are added when we want caffe to **randomly** initialize the weights of the layer, usually when we start training from scratch. If you start training from existing model (i.e. fine tuning) there is no meaning for these arguments.
- `std` value is computed based on the fan-in and fan-out (i.e., number of in-channels and out channels) in order to keep the statistics of the Blob values roughly zero-mean and unit variance.
  You can find an analysis of these parameters in [*Kaiming He, Xiangyu Zhang, Shaoqing Ren, Jian Sun* **Delving Deep into Rectifiers: Surpassing Human-Level Performance on ImageNet Classification** (arXiv 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852).

Comment: Thank you so much for helpful comments and the paper.

Comment: @S.EB very nice paper. I am very fond of `"PReLU"` activation presented there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing it. I really enjoyed reading the [other paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.00847) that you previously introduced for the net design. I am sure this one will be very helpful as well. Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge. I am trying to improve my poor knowledge in the area :")